# How to read dynamically populated checkbox values in Laravel along with checkbox id and value?

Tags: checkbox, laravel-4

I have been able to dynamically populate checkboxes in my view. But I am having problem in reading the checked checkboxes in my controller. I want id, name and value of the checkboxes. For example, if I have two checkboxes, then I want each checkbox's id, name and value indicating whether checked or not. Right now all I am getting is an array that just gives values 1.

I have the view:

```
<div class="control-group">
            {{ Form::label('permission-lbl', 'Permissions') }}
            <div class="controls">
                            @foreach($permissions as $p)
                {{ Form::checkbox('permissions[]',$p->id,false,array('class'=>'permission')) }}&nbsp;{{Form::label('permissions[]',$p->name)}}
                            @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
```

And the controller is:

```
public function store() {
        $validation = new CreateGroupValidator;

        if ($validation->passes()) {
            try {
                // Create the group
                $permissions = Input::get('permissions');
                if(is_array($permissions))
                {
                    //i need each checkbox's id, name and value here                    
                }

                $group = Sentry::createGroup(array(
                    'name'        => Input::get('name')
                )); 

                Notification::success('New group was saved.');
                return Redirect::route('admin.groups.index');
            } 
            catch (\Cartalyst\Sentry\Groups\GroupExistsException $e)
            {
                Notification::error('A group with same name already exists.');
            }
        }

        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation->errors);
    }
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions array that you'll receive from the form will be in this form:

```
// In the form [position] => Input `Value` Attribute
[permissions] => Array ( 
       [0] => 1,
       [1] => 2,
)
```

Where the `key` is the position of the element in the array (not-useful), and the `value` is the attribute `value` of all the inputs that were checked.

In your specific case the Input Value Attribute is the value of `$p->id` in each iteration of the loop.

Have in mind that you will only receive the checkbox that were checked in the form, if no one is checked, you will receive an empty array.

Comment: That means no way out to get the texts associated with each checkbox? Then can this be achieved by putting each checkbox with different ids (that is, not grouping the checkboxes with name = "permissions[]")?

Comment: @sangam a HTML Form will only send to the server the information that is inside an Input/Select/Textarea element, the `label` tag doesn't get send over.

For your specific case I see that you are receiving the `$permission` id that the user selected, this way you could get the permission from the persistency object.

If you really really need the name, you could do a little hack **(Not Recommended)** and to the value attribute put the `$p->id.'-'.$p->name`, and in the server do a split of what you get.

Comment: thank you for the another way around. I think having the form $p->id.'-'.$p->name would save me some database hits. Still since I am getting ids, i have better fetch associated names from db. Thank you so much.